# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus

I was evaluating $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$ using Table of Integrals.

**My work**

I was evaluating $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$ using Table of Integrals. I found in the Table of Integrals an integral that is akin to 
$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$. The integral I was talking about is $$\int \frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2+a^2}} = -\frac{1}{a} ln \left( \frac{a+\sqrt{u^2+a^2}}{u} \right)$$

With that in mind, I need to modify $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$ to look like $\int \frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2+a^2}}$.

Modifying now:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}} = \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{4x^2+1}} = \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}}$$

The modified integral to be evaluated would be $\int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}}$.

Now getting the integral:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}} = \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}} = -2\left(\left(\frac{1}{(1)}\right) ln \left( \frac{(1)+\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}}{(2x)} \right) \right)$$
$$ \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}} = -2 ln \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}{2x} \right) $$
$$ \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}} =  ln \left(\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}{2x} \right)^{-2} \right)$$
$$ \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}} =  \frac{1}{ln \left(\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}{2x} \right)^2 \right)}$$
$$ \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}} = ln \left( \frac{4x^2}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$$

So...the integral of $\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$ would be $ln \left( \frac{4x^2}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$. But in the book I used, it is 
$ln \left( \frac{x}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$. It was so close to my answer, yet I don't know where I messed up.

Where did I messed up?

Comment: "using Table of Integrals" what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: There are many problems in your work. Please review the log rules.

Comment: You're using the substitution $u = 2x$... What is $du$ in terms of $dx$?

Comment: After the first equal sign after "Now getting the integral: ..." you have a missing $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Table of Integrals is a list of common integrals.....It was usually printed at the end of the book.....so it's a handy reference.....The problem asks me to evaluate the integral above using a Table of Integral", so I followed.....

Comment: Hm, okay. I've never gotten my hands on a calculus textbook per se, so I wouldn't know what such a thing were @PalautotKa

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You can find a sample of "Table of Integrals"  in the Internet to know what it look like.....and I edited my post...referring to  "Now getting the integral: ..." you have a missing 2 in the denominator. "

Comment: Hm, okay. I usually know the basic integrals off the top of my head or ask WolframAlpha for quick things.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I must be a dinosaur.......ahahahahah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After "Now getting the integral", when you use the formula, you introduce a $2$ that should not be there. You would get
$$
-\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}{x}\right)
=\ln\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right).
$$
You also need to review the rules for logarithms. It is not true that $\ln 1/x=1/\ln x$ (you used it twice, so it actually "cancelled itself", but it is stil wrong).

Comment: I thought $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$ would be the same as $\frac{2}{2x\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$ or $\frac{2}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}}$

Comment: Exactly, so the two $2$ you need cancel each other, and you don't need to introduce a $2$ in the formula.

Comment: Oh I get it now! That "$2$"!  Thanks for helping me out, man! I get it when you said "you don't need to introduce a 2 in the formula."......

Comment: Wait...what about this operation? $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{4x^2+1}} = \int \frac{2dx}{2x\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}} = -\left(\frac{1}{(1)}\right) ln \left( \frac{(1)+\sqrt{(2x)^2+(1)^2}}{(2x)} \right)$.......I was using this integral $\int \frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2+a^2}} = -\frac{1}{a} ln \left( \frac{a+\sqrt{u^2+a^2}}{u} \right)$.......Why is it that it becomes $\ln\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$ instead of $  ln \left( \frac{2x}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$?

Comment: You missed the minus sign.

Comment: Where's the minus sign? What part of the operation?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was thinking about something else. That $2$ makes no difference. The antiderivative is not unique. Both $\ln\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$ and $\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$ are valid antiderivatives, they differ by a constant.